# sbt compile in Compile meaning

Tags: sbt

Can someone kindly explain what each `compile` and `Compile` mean in this cryptic sbt idiom:

```
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(Def.task { 
  println("task is running") // or whatever code here in the body
})
```

Answer (score 2):

- `compile` means the compile task, as opposed to, say, `package`
- `Compile` means the compile configuration (derived from/matches Apache Ivy's configurations), as opposed to, say, `Test`

It might be easier to understand if you consider `compile in Test` which is the `compile` task scoped to the `Test` configuration and therefore compiles the test sources.

Moreover, the "unscoped" `compile` key isn't actually defined in the defaults of sbt so when you execute `compile` in the shell what's actually executed is `compile in Compile` due to sbt's "delegation rules", which you can read about in the [Scope delegation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scope-Delegation.html) sbt docs.

Comment: Well this still keeps things as cryptic as possible :) why would a `compile` task have a `Test` configuration? How would a `compile` task do something but compile... these are things that need to become crystal clear in an answer to this question I am afraid

Comment: `compile in Test` will compile your tests sources. `compile` doesn't do anything else but compile, but it's about what it compiles.

Comment: This is still rather fuzzy. Perhaps I would be able to compile a cohesive answer if I knew what role does `(compile in Compile)` play here.

Comment: @matt this might help you, Here is the soure of "compile" TaskKey http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/sxr/sbt/Keys.scala.html#sbt.Keys.compile  and the Configuration source of "Compile" configuration http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/sxr/sbt/Configuration.scala.html#sbt.Configurations.Compile  Test configuration is extended with Runtime configuration and Runtime  configuration is extended to Compile configuration

Comment: And also read about scopes  and keys http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html#The+whole+story+about+keys  The scope here is (Compile) and the key is (compile)